# The timeout period ... IN LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

While executing the down lines of my C# controller code I was getting

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I use linq to sql in my c#.and result show my report form.my reporter is rdlc.

I tried like set the connect Timeout = 0; also, but I get the same error.

How can I solve it?
please help me...thanks.

```
private void bt10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        var DB = new DataClasses3DataContext();
        var c1 = (from c in DB.A
                    join r in DB.A1
                    on c.DATE equals r.DATE
                    where c.B.Equals(int.Parse(txtSearch.Text))
                       && (string.Compare(c.DATE.ToString(), txtEdate.Text) <= 0 
                       && string.Compare(c.DATE.ToString(), txtFdate.Text) >= 0)
                       && (c.NO == r.NO)
                       && (c.K == 10)
                       && (c.A == 1)
                       && (r.A == 2)
                       && r.K != 10
                    select c).ToList();    

        dataGridView1.DataSource = c1;
        DataSet2.ADataTable dt = new DataSet2.ADataTable();

        foreach (A item in c1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.B, item.DATE, item.NO, item.K); 
        }

        if (c1 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("null");
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            frm3.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rds.Name = "DataSet3";
            rds.Value = dt;
            frm3.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            frm3.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "P10.Report5.rdlc";
            frm3.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DB.CommandTimeout = 60; // seconds [See this question on LINQ to SQL timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8970112/45852)

Answer (score 1):

Don't "fix" timeouts by increasing them. Fix the underlying problem!

It's very likely that converting`c.DATE` to string before comparing it causes the problem. This makes the expression non-sargable, i.e. any index on `DATE` is disabled. You should change this by parsing `txtEdate.Text` and `txtFdate.Text` first, and use the parsed values in the comparison (and also parse `txtSearch` first).

```
var edate = DateTime.Parse(txtEdate.Text);
var fdate = DateTime.Parse(txtFdate.Text);
var searchInt = int.Parse(txtSearch.Text);

...
where c.B == searchInt
   && c.DATE <= edate 
   && c.DATE >= fdate
...
```

If this still doesn't help you should investigate proper indexing on the database tables. For such a relatively simple query you just shouldn't get a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CommandTimeout** Property That adds to the default time out which is 30 seconds:

```
DB.CommandTimeout = 1 * 60; // Adds 1 Minute to the time out, so 1:30 minutes now
```

If this is a long running task, you might need to consider an async method.

For More : [DataContext.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)