# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. with showing package path

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am uploading a mdb file from asp.net upload control into my sql server database. 
When I am uploading file it is calling a stored procedure from my database in which  I m executing my SSIS packages. Whenever I am calling my stored procedure after few seconds I m getting the exception with showing the path of my packages.

> $exception    {"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.\r\ndtexec /F
>   \"C:\DTSX\DTSXPackage\DTSXPackage\Package.dtsx\""}    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

As I read for solution. Read about Command timeout property of SQL. But still issue is same.
When I m running stored procedure through SQL server it is running fine but when calling it through the asp.net code it giving exception.

```
stack  trace -

>
```

> StackTrace    "   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()\r\n 
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()\r\n 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()\r\n
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte&
>   value)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object
>   instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
>   DataAccessLayer.EspaceDatasetDataContext.ETL_IMPORT_09_01(Nullable`1
>   userId, String clientMachineIP, String loadType, Nullable`1 instId,
>   Nullable`1 bIsIgnoreErrors, Nullable`1& rcout)

stored procedure calling method:-

```
public int? RunDTSxProcess(long userID, string clientMachineIP, string loadType, long instID, bool ignoreErrors)
        {
            try
            {
                int? result = 0;
                var run = database.storedproc(userID, clientMachineIP, loadType, instID, ignoreErrors,ref result);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the code calling this and how are you setting your CommandTimeout, could you show both bit of code ? How long is it taking to throw this exception?

Comment: I read about CommandTimeout property but as I am using linq to sql class i didnt set that property.

Comment: after near to 1min it throwing exception

Comment: i mentioned method where i am calling my stored procedure

Comment: How about setting command timeout in ssis

Comment: I didnt set any command timeout in ssis also not connection timeout . It is default. It is possiblr to set command timeout in LINQ To SQL class file

Comment: when I am executing stored procedure from sql server it is taking 12:42 min for complete execution.

Comment: is database your MainContext variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking to do something with MainContext for your linq to sql as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969751/linq-to-sql-timeout/8970112).

taken from the above answer:

```
using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
{
    db.CommandTimeout = 3 * 60; // 3 Mins
}
```

Comment: can i set the timeout inside of my method which i mentioned above

Comment: I set CommandTimeout=13*60 in my method but after this timeout it still showing me the same exception